# Check AWS RDS reserved instance (shows no Region at the moment)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-reserved-instances

I lunched a reserved instance for RDS yesterday. I waited for the billing to be updated till today morning (it takes normally 6 hours to a day). Now when I go to the Billing the reserved instance and on-demand instance, both are active and being charged. I was hoping once I created the reserved instance of same `instance type`, `AZ`, `Tenancy` the reserved instance would apply to the on-demand instance.

**My on-demand aurora mysql instance look like this:**

[image]

**My Reserved Instance:**

[image]

**My Billing overview:**

[image]

======== Edit

Apparently, It takes 24 hours to takes RI to take effect so that on demand instance can use it. There was nothing wrong with what I've done... just needed some time.

Comment: You can contact AWS Customer Service (which is different to AWS Support) to discuss billing matters. Let us know what they tell you!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein just created a case.. will update! thanks for the info.. I didn't know about AWS customer service!